# Threads communication in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to learn how to use threads in Java. Currently I'm stuck at one exercise where I have three threads A, B and C, each with a local array. I want to make the three threads communicate with each other so that they can find the lowest possible number that is mutual (intersected) to all of the local arrays. If there is such a number I want the thread B to print it and close other threads, if there is no such number my intent is to close the program. What could be the possible solution? How to communicate the information between threads in that scenario?
Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyThread implements Runnable {
    private Thread thrd;
    private Random randomInteger;
    private int[] localArray;

    MyThread(String name, int sizeOfLocalArray) {
        localArray = new int[sizeOfLocalArray];
        randomInteger = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < localArray.length; i++) {
            localArray[i] = randomInteger.nextInt();
        }

        Arrays.sort(localArray);

        thrd = new Thread(this, name);
        thrd.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(thrd.getName() + " starting");

        for (int number : localArray) {
            System.out.println(number + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println(thrd.getName() + " terminating");
    }

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread myThread = new MyThread("threadF", 5);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Well, threads are objects and can communicate with each other just like other objects. I suggest solving it first without threads: just three ordinary classes with local arrays.

Comment: Can you show more of your work?  For example, I only see one thread in the above application.  How are the multiple threads started?  How are they sharing the `localArray`?

Comment: l have no idea how to solve it. l've tried numerous ways. l made it without threads, but I don't see it how it could apply to threads now. How to find the smallest number common to all the three local tables, that each is different inside the three threads. Thanks for the answers so far. l read them all. But, any further help would be great. How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a shared variable to accomplish this but be careful to synchronize access to it. You can access the shared variable by passing it to each thread via it's constructor. I recommend wrapping the shared variable in a class so you can synchronize access.

```
Class ArrayHolder{
    private int[] localArray;

    public ArrayHolder(){
         //initialize vars here 
    }

    public synchronized int lowerstInterection(int[] intArray){
        //write the logic here
    }
}
```

Now when you construct your threads pass it the ArrayHolder via the constructor like so

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         ArrayHolder arrayHolder = new ArrayHolder()
         MyThread myThread = new MyThread("threadF", 5, arrayHolder);
         MyThread myThread = new MyThread("threadG", 5, arrayHolder);
         MyThread myThread = new MyThread("threadH", 5, arrayHolder);
    }    
}
```